# Problem of stochastic differential equation (SDE)

Tags: options, finance, sde, stochastic

[image]

Please help to answer this stochastic differential equation (SDE). Thank you very much.

Comment: Tell us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 4):

We assume that the price at time $t$ of a zero-coupon bond, with maturity $u$ and unit face value, is of the form
\begin{align*}
f(u-t, r_t, x_t) = E\left(e^{-\int_t^u r_s ds}\mid \mathcal{F}_t\right).
\end{align*}
Note that
\begin{align*}
M(t, r_t, x_t) &\equiv f(u-t, r_t, x_t) e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds} \\
&=E\left(e^{-\int_0^u r_s ds} \mid \mathcal{F}_t \right)
\end{align*}
is a martingale. Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
dM &= - r f e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}dt + e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}df\\
&= e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}\bigg[- r f dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}dt + \frac{\partial f}{\partial r} dr_t + \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} dx_t\\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}d\langle r, r\rangle_t + \frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}d\langle x, x\rangle_t + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r\partial x}d\langle r, x\rangle_t \bigg]\\
&=e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}\bigg[\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} - r f + \kappa_r(x-r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \kappa_x(\theta - x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \\
&\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad + \frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta r)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}  + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} \bigg]dt\\
& \quad +e^{-\int_0^t r_s ds}\left[ \sqrt{\alpha + \beta r_t}\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}dB_r(t) + \sigma \sqrt{x} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dB_x(t)\right].
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial t} - r f + \kappa_r(x-r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \kappa_x(\theta - x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta r)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}  + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=0.
\end{align*}
In term of $\tau = u-t$, 
\begin{align*}
-\frac{\partial f}{\partial \tau} - r f + \kappa_r(x-r)\frac{\partial f}{\partial r} + \kappa_x(\theta - x) \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{1}{2}(\alpha + \beta r)\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial r^2}  + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}=0.
\end{align*}
The remaining derivation of the Ricaati equation is then straightforward.

Comment: Ever helpful and clear but you basically did their homework for them!